# Two key attributes in an EER, what does it mean?

Tags: primary-key

I'm currently drawing an EER diagram and stumbled across this problem:

Let's say I'm modeling a workplace where all employee's uniquely can be identified by their name (ie no employees share the exact same name) and their employee number. Is this a correct way to model it?

[image]

I'm not really sure on whether this is an ok design. Does this design say that *Name* and *Emp_nr* **together** form a unique Employee, or does it say that *Name* and *Emp_nr* independently from each other can identify my Employee? I've been searching everywhere and couldn't find a single example on where 2 key attributes is used.

Answer (score 0):

This only tells that an Employee has two **attributes** which are bith a combined primary key

1. he has a name and
2. a employer number

In a Table structure , it will be displayer as two columns for the Table Employee and the would have a PRIMARY KEY(Emp_nr,Name)

```
Employee
-------
Emp_nr

Name
```

Comment: If neither was underlined, they would be regular attributes. I believe underlining an attribute in an EER makes it a *key* attribute. In this regard, the OP's question appears to be how to make it look that the two attributes are two independent keys instead of their being a single composite key.

Comment: you are right they bit are opart of a combined primary key, i forgot that to mention